# why is my variable undefined in reactjs with web3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js

I am trying to use reactJS to show the balance of an Ethereum wallet with web3.
My code successfuly gets the balance and outputs it to the console, however when i try to assign it as a variable and display it in html i get the following error:
**Line 19:37:  'etherval' is not defined  no-undef**

The script:

```
import React from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3'

export default function balances() {

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://****'));
web3.eth.getBalance("0x****", function(err1, balance) {
{
    console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH")
    const etherval = web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether");
  }
})

  return (
    <div className="details">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
                      <h2>Balance: {etherval}</h2>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i have tried to initialise the variable with let but this produces more errors, how can i fix this?

Comment: Because `const` are block scoped, so `etherval` only exists inside the getBalance callback.

Comment: I think the problem is in: const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://****));
You are missing a '. I should read const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://****'));

Comment: @GaneshBudhathoki this was my mistake when i removed the url from the example, i have fixed it, thanks

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks, can you post a working example?

Comment: what @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is saying is declaring a const inside a block makes it a local scope and you are trying to access it outside of the scope. make that const a var

Comment: @GaneshBudhathoki i changed it to :    var etherval = web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether"); but i still get the same error

Comment: vars have function scope and etherval is inside a function  `function(err1, balance)`

Comment: don't use `var`, that's from an era of JS that we no longer live in. Use `let` for values that are going to change, or get assigned later, and use `const` for values that you immediately assign and then never change again. But even if you do that as properly as possible, that won't actually work because your return statement will happen _well_ before you get that value. That `etherval` is state data, and you should be using [the useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3'

export default function Balances() {

const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0)
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://****'));
web3.eth.getBalance("0x****", function(err1, balance) {
{
    console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH")
    setBalance(web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether"));
  }
})

  return (
    <div className="details">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
                      <h2>Balance: {balance}</h2>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can use useState hook and assign the value once you have it. If this version doesn't render the correct amount, you can use useEffect hook also

Comment: for this i get error:   Line 7:31:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "balances" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 12:5:  'setBalance' is not defined                                                                                                                                                                                                                     no-undef

Comment: i changed component to capital letter but still get this error:   Line 12:5:  'setBalance' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: I made a typo sorry. when I declared the state on top, it should be like this :
const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0). I also edited it now

Comment: is there an extra block inside the function passed to `getBalance`?

Comment: hmm still same error:   Line 12:5:  'setBalance' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: did you import useState?

Comment: yeah im using exact same code

Comment: sorry I went to sleep, were you able to fix it at some point?

Answer (score 0):

get the balance in useEffect and set it in state:

```
import { useEffect,useState } from "react";


const [balance, setBallance] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    const loadBalance = async () => {
      // make sure web3 is properly
      const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://****'));
      const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(addressHere)
      setBallance(web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether"))
    }

    loadBalance()
  }, [])
```

Comment: thanks but can you show how to put this in my example?

Comment: this works too!! :D he is already doing it just enclose in useEffect

Comment: @GaneshBudhathoki No way :)

Comment: @Yilmaz by he I was referring to you but okay.

Comment: @GaneshBudhathoki I know.  i was joking :)